# Uncaught TypeError: Object (...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, preact

I'm very new to Preact and when I want to use hooks in Preact, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

And I don't know what to do and there is a little articles in web for Preact

This is my code

```
import './style';
import { useState } from 'preact';

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const increment = useCallback(() => setValue(value + 1), [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      Counter: {value}
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Did any of the answers fix your issue?

Comment: nope it fixed by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're importing it wrong. Should be:

```
import { useState } from 'preact/hooks';
```

See docs here: https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/hooks/#usestate

Answer (score 2):

```
import './style';
import { useState } from 'preact';

const App = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const increment = useCallback(() => setValue(value + 1), [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      Counter: {value}
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I think you forgot to import useCallback hook. It should be                                 
 import { useState,useCallback  } from 'preact/hooks';